# How to remove whole row from php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I deleted the row from database but i want to remove the row from interface in php page also.Any help will be appreciated.

mypage.php

```
<tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
       <td><div class="delete_class" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</div></td>
</tr>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete_class").click(function(){
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'check.php',
      data:'delt_id='+del_id,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) {   alert("successfully deleted data");
        } else { // DO SOMETHING }
      }
   });
 });
});

check.php
$id = $_POST['delt_id'];
$query = "delete from TABLE NAME where ID = $id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `remove()` the `<tr>` element.

```
// you currently have this   
var del_id = $(this).attr('id');

// add this, step up to td, step up to tr
var $tableRow = $(this).parent().parent();

// or add this, finds the nearest tr
var $tableRow = $(this).closest('tr');

// then remove it (once you know the request was successful)
$tableRow.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to remove it client side inside success callback (if success only fired when you are sure the row as been deleted server side from datatabase):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".delete_class").click(function () {
        var del_id = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            context: this, // << set it for keeping context in jqXHR callbacks
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'check.php',
            data: 'delt_id=' + del_id,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    alert("successfully deleted data");
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                } else { 
                     // DO SOMETHING ELSE
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```